# Node.js App Crashing Constantly - memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-cloud

I have a Node.js app that is basically the boilerplate that CONSTANTLY crashes due to this error:

```
an instance of the app crashed: out of memory
```

I have no idea how this app could crash with 256mb of memory. It does almost nothing server side beside respond to http requests and I am wondering how this could be. Garbage collection problem?

app.js

```js
require('newrelic'); //monitoring

var express = require('express');//middleware
var app = express();

var cfenv = require('cfenv');// Cloud Foundry library
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(appEnv.port, appEnv.bind, function() {
 console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});
```

**UPDATE**
[This appears to be the issue](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/memory-leaking-only-with-node-js-agent-installed/14448/39). Can't do anything at this point but remove the service. :(

Comment: Feel like posting any code?

Comment: This thread seems to imply there's an ongoing issues with a newrelic memory leak (https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/memory-leaking-only-with-node-js-agent-installed/14448/36).

Comment: jmar777 - sounds like that is the problem. Thanks for finding that link

Comment: @jmar777 From my read of https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/9064/files it sounds like the problem is with the core Node code itself in the area of tls (SSL) connections when they finish.  Per benrondeau: "This memory leak is crashing my Node app in 3-5mins with 256mb of memory!!"

Answer (score 0):

when running an app in a low memory environment, it can happen that garbage collection is not triggered early enough. You can invoke it manully and see if that helps.

Add `--expose-gc`to the start command of your app - e.g.:

```
node --expose-gc myapp.js
```

Then in your code do this periodically:

```
Global.gc()
```

In order to monitor the memory consumption of your app you can do a cf curl:

```
cf curl /v2/apps/<your app guid>
```

Comment: Sounds more like a leak to me, tbh.